# "GL_HALF_FLOAT" with OpenGL Rendering and GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, floating-point-precision, renderer

I am programming an OpenGL renderer in C++. I want it to be as efficient as possible and each vertex/normal/UV tex coord/tangents/etc to take up as little memory as possible. I am using indexes, line strips, and fans. I was thinking that 32bit floating points are not necessary and 16 bit Floating points should be fine, at least for some of these like normals and UVs. I can't seem to find any examples of this anywhere. I can find talk of "GL_HALF_FLOAT", but no real examples. Am I on the right track? Or is this not worth looking in to? If anyone knows of an example of this could they send a link of source code?

Comment: You can pack and unpack 2 half-floats using a `uint` data type. But the smallest data type you're going to get in GLSL is 32-bit. See [`uint packHalf2x16( vec2 v)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/packHalf2x16.xhtml) for more details.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman You can have `HALF_FLOAT` data in vertex buffers. It will of course be extended to 32-bit precision once it reaches the shader, but you still save memory space and bandwidth if half-float is enough precision for your coordinates.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: I completely misread the question because my mind was elsewhere :-\ I sort of saw the tag and thought he wanted to change the precision of `float` in GLSL. Yes, you're absolutely right - though since half-floats aren't a part of most languages something like glm (assuming this is C++) will have to fill that role.

Answer (score 5):

In full OpenGL (unlike in OpenGL ES), shader code always operates with 32-bit floats. Starting with OpenGL 3.0, specifying vertex data as half-floats is supported, though. If the precision is sufficient for your needs, this can reduce memory usage for your vertex data, and reduce the bandwidth needed for vertex fetching.

Keep in mind that the precision of a half-float is only about 3-4 decimal digits. So the accuracy really is seriously limited.

As for how to use them, it's quite straightforward. If you have a pointer to half-float values, you store them in a VBO using `glBufferData()` or `glBufferSubData()`, just like you would for any other type. The `glVertexAttribPointer()` call will then look like this, using an attribute with 3 components as an example:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, GL_HALF_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);
```

The format of the data itself is defined in the [ARB_texture_float](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_float.txt) extension. While it's not officially named, it looks at least very similar to the [IEEE 754-2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) format. I wrote conversion code based on that Wikipedia format description before, and it worked fine for OpenGL usage.

Most languages don't have built-in types for half-floats. So you either will have to write a few lines of code to do the conversion from float to half-float, or use code that somebody else wrote.

The following resources about half-float conversion are from a quick search. I have no personal experience with any of them, and you should do your own search to find the one most suitable for your needs:

- Interesting article from Intel, explaining possible performance benefits: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/performance-benefits-of-half-precision-floats. This also mentions that Intel processors have instructions for the conversion (e.g. there's a `_mm256_cvtps_ph` intrinsic to convert from float to half-float).
- Open source library for half-float operations and conversions: http://half.sourceforge.net/.
- gcc documentation saying that it supports a half-float type (`__fp16`) for ARM targets.